# How to trigger Archive php if statement?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a code for Archive.php page inside Wordpress but i have hard time figuring out how to trigger particular if statement (`is_year()` and `is_month()` ). For example i would like to output ***Yearly Archives*** on my page but I have no idea how to achieve that. 
I tried changing permalinks and changing date format inside "General Settings" but no matter I do it always outputs: *"Monthly archives:"*. 

***So What do I need to change to trigger that particular output? (Daily Archives: or Yearly Archives:)***

```
<header class="page-header">
 <h1 class="page-title">
 <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'domain' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
 <?php elseif ( `is_month()` ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'domain' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'domain' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
 <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'domain' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'domain' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php _e( 'Blog Archives', 'domain' ); ?>

</h1>
</header>
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?><?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

   <div class="entry">                  
    <?php the_content( __( 'Read more', 'domain' ) ); ?>    

    </div><!--/entry-->
    </div><!--/post_class-->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?><!--END if THE LOOP-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any problem with your conditionals. What do you get displayed, when you access your site like so example.com/2013, you get yearly archive, elseif example.com/2013/11 monthly archive, elseif example.com/2013/11/19, daily archive? (If a particular archive does not exists, you get 404, not empty archive)